# Como hago para que dure unos segundos una accion? Unity c#

Tags: c#, unity, 3d

Necesito ayuda en una accion, osea supongamos que tengo una funcion de colision, lo que quiero hacer es que cuando el objeto player choque contra ese objeto que tiene el metodo colision mi player se vuelva de color rojo por el momento en el que ha entrado en el campo de colision y luego cuando salga de ahi que vuelva a su color o material original, es lo que quiero hacer, pero no se como, agradezco ayuda de antemano
Tengo este codigo en colisiones:

```
 
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
```

public class colisionvida : MonoBehaviour {
    int Dano = 0;

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider otro){
    Debug.Log ("Colisiona");
    otro.gameObject.SendMessageUpwards ("QuitarVida", Dano, SendMessageOptions.DontRequireReceiver);
}
```

}

Y este en vida:

```
void start(){gameObject.GetComponent().material = materialB;}
```

void QuitarVida (int Dano) {
        Vida -= Dano;
        gameObject.GetComponent().material = materialA;
}

Comment: Para que podamos ayudarte, debes enseñar el código con lo que has intentado hacer y cuál es el problema específico.

Comment: y si intenrtas colocar un animacion sobre el person para que cuando tenga la colicion lo llamas

Comment: Y como haria eso? estuve buscando lado para hacer la animacion de cambio de color del objeto pero no entiendo del todo, osea, practicamente no se como hacerlo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bueno, ya lo solucione, lo que hice fue usar el "yield return new WaitForSeconds (.06f);"
Cree un IEnumerator aparte:

```
IEnumerator returne(){
        yield return new WaitForSeconds (.06f);
        GetComponent ().material.SetColor ("_Color", Color.white);
    }
```

Luego use el void donde tenia la accion de cambiar el color:

```
void color(){
        GetComponent ().material.SetColor ("_Color", Color.red);
        StartCoroutine ("returne");
    }
```

Y luego en el void donde se quita la vida llame a color():

```
void QuitarVida (int Dano) {
        color ();
}
```

Y listo